# Firebase auth: switching providers

Tags: oauth, firebase-authentication

I'm currently building an application that uses sign in with Twitter. However, some users report losing their Twitter account (or also possibly getting banned from Twitter, etc), and am wondering if it's possible to switch those accounts to Google signin or email signin.  Have not found docs on this, especially if the linked identifier is a Twitter handle instead of an email.  Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: So you want to link an existing Twitter account with Google?

Comment: The existing account is suspended so can't quite link - but for an unsuspended account, linking is probably the best option it seems

Answer (score 0):

check here --> https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking

But I think that the user must be logged in to do so, as you comment if they do not have how to enter with Twitter what you could do is a validation of additional data you have of the user (indicate their name, twitter user, something that you know about him) in a section that you build within the platform where new users can request to claim an account.

Comment: Seems like we'll just build the linking layer but for accounts that have been suspended probably not much we can do since they can't link if they're suspended... a bit gnarly

Comment: :c ,  try Supabase, which has native support for multiple accounts and works great, also because is PostgreSQL behind them you get the most of a battle-tested DB like full-text search and a lot of other community modules.